# How to pass arguments to std::vector::insert()?

Tags: c++

I am new around Classes so I cannot pass arguments to `std::vector::insert()`:

```
//myclass.h
class myClass//: private std::vector<char>
{ 
private:
typedef char mytype;
typedef std::vector<mytype> vector;
vector Store;

...

/* iterators */
const vector::const_iterator begin() const
{
    return Store.begin() ;
}
const vector::const_iterator end() const
{
    return Store.end();
}
vector::iterator begin()
{
    return Store.begin() ;
}
vector::iterator end()
{
    return Store.end();
}
template<class Iter>
void insert(vector::const_iterator c, Iter a, Iter b)
{
    Store.insert(c,a,b); //error
}
```

Gives error when I compile a .cpp included that .h file.
Could anyone help me? thanks in advance.

> [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::vector::insert(std::vector::const_iterator&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >&)'

Comment: what do you mean by `function of a vector`?

Comment: @Slava read it as "... I cannot pass arguments to 'insert function' of a vector"

Comment: @R_Kapp Yeap didn't see that.

Comment: How are you calling your insert function?

Comment: @Kevin I see, thanks

Comment: Though this is not error, I would recommend something else that `vector` for that typedef name, for example `cvector` (char vector), otherwise you may have problems with name collision.

Comment: thanks guys. the problem has been fixed.
@Slava I agree with you I will change that to 'cvector'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you are using pre-C++11 compiler. Before C++11, vector::insert took the first iterator as non-const - and your function uses const_iterator.

Either upgrade the compiler or change signature of your insert to accept non-const iterator.